# Import csv into sql with GUID created

Tags: sql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I have a database that I need to add to.  The columns are in the order (ID, username, email, data, data, data,...).

The ID column is filled with unique GUIDs.

My csv file has the correct number of columns, but the ID column is empty.  I want to import the csv file and have a unique GUID created for the ID column as everything is imported.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

USE NEWID() for ID column in your import insert script.